# Kibana is not connecting with elasticsearch shield SSL

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, kibana-4

We are try to set up the shield SSL in local machine.

```
Elasticsearch version : 2.2.1
Kibana version : 4.4.1
Shield version : Latest version
```

We generated self signed crt, key, pem file as below:

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
openssl req -out CSR.csr -key privateKey.key -new
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey privateKey.key
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -out certificate.pem
keytool -importcert -keystore node01.jks -file certificate.pem -alias my_ca
keytool -certreq -alias node01 -keystore node01.jks -file CSR.csr -keyalg rsa -ext san=dns:XXX.com,ip:XXXX.xxxx.xxx
keytool -importcert -keystore node01.jks -file Certificate-signed.crt -alias node01
openssl x509 -in Certificate-signed.crt -out node01-signed-noheaders.crt
```

and added in shield configuration.

Shield configuration:

```
shield.http.ssl: true
shield.transport.ssl: true
shield.ssl.keystore.key_password: XXXXX
shield.ssl.keystore.password: XXXX
shield.ssl.keystore.path: /es/config/shield/node01.jks
network.host: XX.XX.XX.XX
```

Kibana configuration:

```
elasticsearch.url: "https://XXXXX:9200"
elasticsearch.username: "username"
elasticsearch.password: "password"
elasticsearch.ssl.cert: /XXX/XXX/XXX/elasticsearchtls.crt
elasticsearch.ssl.key: /XXX/XXX/XXX/elasticsearchtls.key
elasticsearch.ssl.ca: /XXX/XXX/XXX/elasticsearch.pem
elasticsearch.ssl.verify: true
```

So when run the kibana the below error is displayed in elasticsearch log:

```
log [12:24:25.512] [error][elasticsearch] Request error, retrying -- self signed certificate
log [12:24:25.622] [warning][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: https://XXXX:9200/
log [12:24:25.624] [warning][elasticsearch] No living connections
log [12:24:25.627] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at https://XXXXXX:9200.
```

After that when I change the `elasticsearch.ssl.verify: false` Kibana is working fine, but showing some error in elasticsearch log:

```
ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for REST request [/_mget?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1461307913497]]
```

In elastic client also the same issue is coming. When we use rejectUnauthorized: true then client is not connecting to elasticsearch.

My questions are:

- is the self signed certificate working in Elasticsearch, Kibana or not?
- do we have to buy a commercial CA certificate?
- are we missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are using unnecessary steps when generating and importing the key. Also the certificate you are generating is not signed by the CA and hence it will never be trusted

Unless you have a large deployment I would just use a selfsigned certificate, rather than a certificate signed by a selfsigned CA.

1) Generate a selfsigned certificate with SAN extensions as indicated here [How can I generate a self-signed certificate with SubjectAltName using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl)

2) Merge the key and certificate in a PKCS12 container and import it to the a java keystore as explained here [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)